# Redirecting specific folder to another folder and load a specific page using httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache, apache2, centos, virtualhost

I have a virtual host: `www.example.com` which contains 2 subfolders namely `hello` and `hello2`. `hello` contains nothing while `hello2` contains a `test.html` file.

Now what I want to do is that whenever I access `www.example.com/hello` I want the page to access `test.html` in `hello2` subfolder.

Sample output:

url: `www.example.com/hello`

after pressing enter,

url: `www.example.com/hello2/test.html`
page display: This is test.html

How am I able to do this **without** using `.htaccess` **just** using `httpd.conf` configuration. I've been stuck for hours.

Here's what I've tried but no luck

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/www.example.com/hello
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        Alias /hello /var/www/www.example.com/hello2
        <Directory /var/www/www.example.com/hello2>
            #Options FollowSymLinks
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteRule ^/index\.html$ test.html [R]
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out putting this in the `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        Alias /hello /var/www/www.example.com/hello2
        RewriteEngine On
        Redirect 301 /hello http://www.example.com/hello2/test.html
</VirtualHost>
```